# Spring FeignClient fallback not called but goes to exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I’m having an issue trying out the feignclient fallback based on the documentation.

Assume myFeignClient can’t connect to myFeign

```
@FeignClient(name = "myFeign", fallback = MyFeignClientFallback.class)
public interface MyFeignClient {
    @PostMapping(“/test")
    Object test(@RequestParam(“param1") String param1);
}
```

My fallback class is this:

```
@Component
public class MyFeignClientFallback implements MyFeignClient {
    public Object test(@RequestParam(“param1”) String param1) {

        return “Error";
    }

}
```

instead of calling the fallback method it just outright fails:

> 2018-05-07 15:19:48.052 ERROR 41592 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: myFeign] with root cause
>
> com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: myFeign

I already have my feign client working. I was experimenting with the idea of using Hystrix when I encountered this issue.

Did I use this incorrectly or did I miss something?

Comment: That's a ribbon error, not feign. Are you using `@EnableDiscoveryClient`? If, so is `myFeign` a registered client? Otherwise have you configured a `listOfServers`?

Comment: @spencergibb looks like you came late to the party. We're about done here. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please enable the hystrix in your configuration file application.yml, the default is false and the function will not work.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    launchScript ()
}

archivesBaseName = 'framework' 
version = '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.RC1'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: //...
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true 

feign:
  hystrix:
    enabled: true
```

Application.java

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

FrameworkHelloService.java

```
package framework.root.service;

import framework.root.service.FrameworkHelloService.HelloServiceFallback;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@FeignClient(name = "framework", fallback = HelloServiceFallback.class)
public interface FrameworkHelloService {
    @GetMapping("/api/hello")
    public String hello();

    @GetMapping("/api/exception")
    public void exception();

    @GetMapping("/none")
    public String none();

    @Component
    class HelloServiceFallback implements FrameworkHelloService {
        @Override
        public String hello() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void exception() { }

        @Override
        public String none() {
            return "Fallback!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That key is no longer supported. @EnableFeignClients already does this.

Comment: I just resolved the problem recently. I'm using spring boot 2.0.1.RELEASE and Cloud Finchley.RC1. This method really work. Of course I've add the annotation before. Are you sure it does not work? If so I can show you a demo.

Comment: Show me your build.gradle file because regardless of the format, spring doesn't recognize that key.

Comment: After some fumbling with the data exchange, I was able to get this working. It was feign.hystrx.enabled after all. Don't know why it's telling me it's not recognized. I'm leaving it alone for now but after using that key, the relevant errors started falling in. It was simply a matter of satisfying the missing stuff moving forward. Thanks!